# Почему выводится весь список значений?

Tags: python

Первый код, он выводит только ключи второго словаря:

```
while 1:
print(""" 
        Choose an option:
        1 - view contacts
        2 - add new contact
        3 - exit the application
    """)
menu = int(input("Your choice:"))
menu
contacts = {
    "Andrew Warrick": {"Andrew Warrick": '','Primary phone:': '123456789',"Phone 2:":'123456789',"E-mail":'@mail.com','telegram':'@telega'},
    "Sofia Kalinina": {"Sofia Kalinina": '','Primary phone:': '175674529',"Phone 2:":'154663452',"E-mail":'sofa@mail.com','telegram':'@sofa'}
}
if menu == 1:
    print("Your contacts:\n")
    for i in contacts.keys():
        print(i)
    print('enter contacts\n')   
    contact = input('Your contact:')
    if contact in contacts:
        for i in contacts[contact]:
            print(i)
```

Когда я добавил условия, мне стал выводиться весь список, когда мне нужно, чтобы  выводился `Ключ:Значение`:

```
 while 1:
            print(""" 
                    Choose an option:
                    1 - view contacts
                    2 - add new contact
                    3 - exit the application
                """)
            menu = int(input("Your choice:"))
            contacts = {
                "Andrew Warrick": {"Andrew Warrick": '',
                    'Primary phone:': '123456789',
                    "Phone 2:":'123456789',
                    "E-mail":'@mail.com',
                    'telegram':'@telega'},
                "Sofia Kalinina": {"Sofia Kalinina": '',
                    'Primary phone:': '175674529',
                    "Phone 2:":'154663452',
                    "E-mail":'sofa@mail.com',
                    'telegram':'@sofa'}
            }
            if menu == 1:
                print("Your contacts:\n")
                for i in contacts.keys():
                    print(i)
                print('enter contacts\n')   
                contact = input('Your contact:')
                if contact in contacts:
                    for i in contacts[contact]:
                        if i in contacts:
                            print(contacts[i])
```

что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Если нужно вывести только одну запись, то надо и выводить только ее, а не в цикле весь словарь.

Comment: Что делает программа и где у вас 1 словарь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понял, что вы хотите вывести, но попробуйте пример:

```
contacts = {
    "Andrew Warrick": {
                       "Andrew Warrick": '',
                       'Primary phone:': '123456789',
                       "Phone 2:": '123456789',
                       "E-mail": '@mail.com',
                       'telegram': '@telega'
                       },
    "Sofia Kalinina": {"Sofia Kalinina": '',
                       'Primary phone:': '175674529',
                       "Phone 2:":'154663452',
                       "E-mail":'sofa@mail.com',
                       'telegram':'@sofa'}
}

print(""" 
    Выберите опцию:
  1 - просмотреть контакты
  2 - добавить новый контакт
  3 - выйти из приложения""")

while 1:
    menu = int(input("\nВыберите опцию: "))

    if menu == 1:
        print("\nСписок контактных лиц:")
        for i in contacts.keys():
            print(i)

        contact = input('\nВведите контактное лицо для просмотра данных: ')
        if contact in contacts:
            for k, v in contacts[contact].items():
                print("{:15}: {}".format(k, v))

    elif menu == 3:
        break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если в цикле проверять наличие каждой записи в словаре на её наличие в этом словаре, то каждая запись и выведется. Нужно сразу печатать то, что нужно, и все

```
contact = input('Your contact:')
if contact in contacts:
    print(contacts[contact])
```

Comment: Да но выводом будет {'Andrew Warrick': '', 'Primary phone:': '123456789', 'Phone 2:': '123456789', 'E-mail': '@mail.com', 'telegram': '@telega'} а мне нужно что вывод был Primary phone:123456789 Phone 2:12345678 и т.д